# Set up default WHERE clause for DBIC relationships

Tags: dbix-class

We have a sizable database with a number of tables containing the field `delete_time`. Rows with a non-null in this field should be excluded from most "normal" queries. So for instance, we have an "Org" object which `has_many` "User" objects. But for most cases, `$org->users` should not include "User" objects with a non-null `delete_time` field.

Now, we could define the `has_many` relationship to exclude these, but this means we'd have to adjust the `...->has_many('users' => '::User', ...)` everywhere. It would be more natural and less error-prone if the `::User` class could apply a "default WHERE clause" that would specify `delete_time IS NULL`, if and only if `delete_time` is not specified in an explicit WHERE clause. (Or maybe if no explicit WHERE clause exists in the `has_many` parameter list; I'm not terribly fussy.)

I was thinking that this could be set up as a trait or plug-in in the `::User` class. Is this remotely possible? I'm looking for encouragement and direction, not necessarily a fleshed-out solution.